# Shopify Multiple Product options, add event to generated dropdown options

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, product, variants

Shopify has existing theme to use products with multiple options as explained here

http://wiki.shopify.com/Tutorial_on_editing_existing_theme_to_use_products_with_multiple_options

Now, let say, i have 2 options for my products "Size and Material". The existing theme allows to select between 2 options SIZE and MATERIAL, but list all the Sizes and Materials on every select options. So when Size and Material did not match it will just appear in Price as UNAVAILABLE and disabled add to cart button.

What i want is that the main selection is Material, whatever the Material selected, it will only lists Sizes that are available with the selected Material, so it means that every time new Material selected, dropdown selection for Sizes will change according the its availability with the selected Material.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll be wanting this: http://wiki.shopify.com/Linked_Options